# Can the font in the badges section be changed?

Tags: feature-request, design

I am new to this SE site, and looking at the badges section, the font is hard to read. Is it possible to either change this font, or make it bigger?

Answer (score 2):

The fonts enumerated for the `.badge` CSS class:

```
+--------------------------+----------+---------------+
| Font name                | Tested ? | Looks good ?  |
+--------------------------+----------+---------------+
| DejaVu Sans Mono         | yes      | yes           |
| Bitstream Vera Sans Mono | yes      | yes           |
| Courier New              | yes      | no, too small |
| Courier                  | yes      | no, too wide  |
| Consolas                 | yes      | yes           |
| Andale Mono WT           |          |               |
| Andale Mono              |          |               |
| Lucida Console           | yes      | yes           |
| Lucida Sans Typewriter   | yes      | yes           |
+--------------------------+----------+---------------+
```

(Tested on Linux with Firefox. If you have the other fonts installed, please edit this answer.)

For now, seems that Courier New is the one to blame. I suggest to remove Courier New and to move Courier as last font specified for `.badge` in all.css:

```
font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono","Bitstream Vera Sans Mono",Consolas,"Andale Mono WT","Andale Mono","Lucida Console","Lucida Sans Typewriter",Courier,monospace;
```

Comment: I guess I should have looked at the CSS...

Comment: Actually I intended to address that "I suggest to" to the site management. I think this should be solved globally.

Comment: The Mac fonts Menlo (especially) and Monaco are quite a bit closer to the "preferred" Vera Sans Mono than the current first likely fallbacks of Courier New or Courier.

Comment: Courier only looks wide because of the peculiarities of Windows font rendering system.

Comment: @kinokijuf, then Linux presents the same peculiarities. Note that I tested those fonts on Linux. I put together a [small test table](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc5VU/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: @manatwork I didn’t know Linux supports bitmap fonts.

Answer (score 2):

With the recent design updates to the site, the badge font is now larger. See [Site Design Updates](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates) for details.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't address your feature request, it is a workaround: in all (modern) web browsers you can increase the size of the fonts on a page with the `zoom` command. In Firefox, for example, this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>.

Alternatively, you could also use an extension like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) and write your own CSS snippet to override the default style.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. It's not completely unreadable, but somewhat annoying.